# Can't connect the camera- what to do?

Tags: camera, xiaomi

I am using Xiaomi Redmi 3s prime. I have an issue came up recently. After clicking 2-3 photos an camera error occurs and it says that "can't connect the camera". Then I need to shut down the camera and then have to try after sometime. How to resolve this issue? Is it a problem of software or hardware? please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try resetting your phone?

Comment: Hard reset is never a good solution. Even rebooting violates Linux philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

There could be two solutions for it:

1. Other Programmes might have been using the camera. Uninstall or force stop that app and try restarting your phone. It should work.
2. Check whether You have given all permissions to camera in security option in settings or in the home screen. Since i had a miui ROM so i know permissions in miui is very hard to handle.

Comment: ok i did restart the phone, it is fine for the time being but I'll ping if it hangs up again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused when another program is using the camera. Have you tried doing a hard restart, killing all apps that have camera permission or look like they may use the camera, Have you checked for spyware of sorts? Do all of these and if you still have problem update your question stating what you've done.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.